# Android app losing state after switching to code sent via SMS

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Context:**

- I have a Xamarin app (using *Xamarin.Forms*)
- Issue is with Android version only.
- There is a reset password form.
- That form sends a request to a server, which issues an SMS with a code.
- The app automatically displays the verification code form, by pushing a new view on the stack.
- The user then checks code in the SMS app, switchesback to my app, and enters the code.

**Problem:**

- Some times the flow above works fine.
- Other times, when the user switches back to my app from the SMS, the app reverts back to the root navigation page.

**Notes:**

I am having trouble identifying the root cause. I suspect that it is due to page activity lifecycle, and that in the scenarios when it doesn't work, the OS has deallocated resources from my app, thus reloads it.

Please see diagram attached.

**Questions:**

1. Is anybody able to suggest a way to debug this so I know for sure
   what is the root cause?

   Is anybody able to suggest a way to handle app switching in Xamarin
   Android so that state is maintained?

[image]

Comment: Just so people know, you are using plain Xamarin.Android and not Xamarin.Forms? The mention of "Page" in the sentence `the app reverts back to the root navigation page` can be synonymous with a Xamarin.Forms page. If it's regular Xamarin.Android I believe you should be able to solve this with a proper activity launch mode. There's a great demo on the store here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.novoda.demos.activitylaunchmode If using Xamarin.Forms it's a whole different story as it currently uses a single activity and swaps content between pages.

Comment: Great pickup @JonDouglas, I am using Xamarin.Forms! I'll update the question. Thank you.

Comment: In this case, you are running into a classic issue of an Activity recreating itself. You can enable `Don't Keep Activities` in your device's settings to demonstrate the application destroying your activity when you "swap" to the SMS app to grab the code. Sadly the easy way to remedy this would be to store the navigation stack and "maintain the state manually" when the activity will recreate itself in `OnCreate()`. Native android uses `OnSaveInstanceState` here to save and `OnRestoreInstanceState` to restore the state. You would "recreate the stack" this way.

Comment: I believe there is an existing proposal for Xamarin.Forms to handle this better internally via the following proposal: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90940

Comment: You can also start a foreground android service to raise your app's importance so the Android OS will consider other resources to collect and free before yours, after returning from the SMS app, you would stop the service and allow your app to return to a standard importance.